# Query data from two tables

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables:

1. user_details: **id**, **firstname**, **lastname**
2. user_timer: **id**, **user_id** (reference by id in user_details), **checkin_date**, **checkin_time**

Now when the user enters a start and end date, I want to produce the results:

when user enter those dates i want output like as under:

**firstname**, **lastname**, **checkin_date**, **checkin_time**

I already perform query for fetching checkin_date and checkin_time:

```
select * from user_timer where `checkin_date` between '$startdate' and '$enddate'
```

now how can I fetch **firstname** & **lastname** using join-query or sub-query.

I want to use only a single query for output. Plz give me suggestion I am NEW in PHP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
select utimer.checkin-date, utimer.checkin-time,  user.firstname, user.lastname
from user_timer utimer
INNER JOIN user_details user ON  utimer.user_id = user.id
where  utimer.checkin_date between '$startdate' and '$enddate'
```

Answer (score 1):

How about something like

```
select  ud.firstname,
        ud.lastname, 
        ut.checkin-date, 
        ut.checkin-time
from    user_timer ut INNER JOIN
        user_details ud ON  ut.user_id = ud.id
where   checkin_date between '$startdate' and '$enddate'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :-

```
select * from user_timer u,user_details ud where ud.checkin_date between '$startdate' and '$enddate' and u.id = ud.id
```

Answer (score 0):

How I would do it:

```
select ut.firstname, ut.lastname, ud.checkin_date, ud.checkin_time from user_timer ut LEFT JOIN user_details ud ON ud.id=ut.user_id  where ut.checkin_date between '$startdate' and '$enddate'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT name, your, fields 
FROM user_details
LEFT JOIN user_timer ON user_details.id = user_timer.user_id
WHERE checkin_date between '$startdate' and '$enddate'
```